# Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle

When running the code i receive the error missing expression

```
select * from medication
where MEDICINE like '%injection'
and where visit date between '01-May-2004' and between '31-May-2004';
```

Comment: change `and where` to `and`.  Also fix `visit date`, whatever that is supposed to be.

Comment: Only one WHERE per SELECT.

Comment: now return the error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Update your SQL to what you've tried.  did you fix the `visit date` as well?

Comment: no need second `between`. also do you mean `visit_date` ?

Comment: Also change `and between` to just `and`... so something like `and visit_date between '01-May-2004' and '31-May-2004'`, though it's better to specify the date format/use ANSI date literals, and if your column has non-midnight times you're losing data from the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Comments were getting to verbose: easier to just show the changes and explain them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM medication
WHERE MEDICINE like '%injection'
  and visit_date between '01-May-2004' and '31-May-2004';
```

- no 2nd where...
- no 2nd between
- visit date needs to be in " " if there is a space and case specific then. or use _ which is prevalent in Oracle  but it really depends on what the column is named.